# Django: Filter data based on expiration date coming within next 1 week and 2 weeks

Tags: django, date, filter, date-range

I have a model class:

```
class Products(models.Model):
   product = models.Charfield(   field specs here .  )
   expiration_date = modelsDateTimeField ( .  field specs here .  )
```

Now I want the users to be able to see all the products which will expire in 1 week or/and 1 month or/and 3 months from today.

I have already tried:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

expiration_date_after = filters.DateFilter(field_name='expiration_date', lookup_expr='gte')
expiration_date_before = filters.DateFilter(field_name='expiration_date', lookup_expr='lte')
```

with this, I have to pass two parameters in the url:

```
/products/?expiration_date_after=2019-06-06&expiration_date_before=2019-06-12
```

But I want to pass in the url only 1 or 2 or 3 which will display data for 1 week, 2 weeks and 3 weeks .

So if i pass products/1 . it should filters expiration date for next 1 week.
and if i pass products/2 . it should filter expiration date for next 1 month.

I am new to django.... So please let me know what is best approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should write query like this:

```
products = Products.objects.filter(expiration_date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

if You want on weekley basis than you should do like this:

```
days = 7*n
start_date = today()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
```

where n=number of weeks

Note: Do not forget to change date string to datetime object

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in this manner:

In custom_filters folder:

```
from Django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from date time import date time, date, timedelta
import datetime

class DaysFromTodayFilter(filters.Filter):

    def filter(self,qs,value):
        if value not in (None,''):
            days_key = int(value):
            today = datetime.date.today()
            if days_key ==1:
                x_days_from_today = today + date time.timedelta(days=7)
            elif days_key ==2:
                x_days_from_today = today + date time.timedelta(days=14)
            return qs.filter(**{'%s__%s'%(self.field_name, 'range'):(today, x_days_from_today)})
        return qs
```

In views.py file:

```
from Django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from views import DaysFromTodayFilter
from models import Products
import Django_filters

class ProductsFilter(Django_filters.FilterSet):
    expiration_date_within = DaysFromTodayFilter(field_name='expiration_date')
```

It's working fine....

in the url:

```
localhost:8000/products/1
```

is filter all products which will expire in 1 week and /2 for two weeks